# Get time interval between two time using php with given duraion using php?

Tags: php

I have start time and end time in php. 
If i give duration it should display all the time intervals.
`Startime =  2014-07-28 07:00:00`
`End Time = 2014-07-28 11:00:00`
`duration = 30 min`

i need output with 30 min difference between start and end time.

Output should look like  :

> 07:00, 07:30 , 08:00 , 08:30 ..... 10:00 , 10:30 , 11:00

Comment: RTFM: [`DateTime::diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)... The class + method name says it all, doesn't it? Also look into `DateInterval` and other related classes, the entire `DateTime` docs will give you everything you need. Play around with those first, if you can't work it out then, show us what you've tried, but try something yourself first

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP time intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233794/php-time-intervals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$s = strtotime("2014-07-28 07:00:00");
$e = strtotime("2014-07-28 11:00:00");
while($s != $e) {
 $s = strtotime('+30 minutes', $s);
 echo date('H:i', $s);
}
```

output :- 07:30 08:00 08:30 09:00 09:30 10:00 10:30 11:00

for comma seperated:-

```
while($s != $e) {
  $s = strtotime('+30 minutes', $s);
  $arr[] = date('H:i', $s);
}
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

output:- 07:30,08:00,08:30,09:00,09:30,10:00,10:30,11:00

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateperiod.php) class for this:

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-07-28 07:00:00');
$end = new DateTime('2014-07-28 11:00:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach($period as $time) {
    echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
2014-07-28 07:00:00
2014-07-28 07:30:00
2014-07-28 08:00:00
2014-07-28 08:30:00
2014-07-28 09:00:00
2014-07-28 09:30:00
2014-07-28 10:00:00
2014-07-28 10:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$start = "2014-07-28 07:00:00";
$end = "2014-07-28 11:00:00";

$start_time = strtotime($start);
$end_time = strtotime($end);

$time_diff = 30 * 60;
for($i=$start_time; $i<=$end_time; $i+=$time_diff)
{
    echo date("H:i", $i).", ";
}
```

See [**WORKING DEMO**](https://eval.in/173110)

Comment: when i use start time between  $start = "2014-07-28 18:00:00"; and endtime $end = "2014-07-29 01:00:00";  output get 0. how can i rectify this